# Interpretation of default Type III Sums in Squares in R

Tags: r, anova, contrasts, f-test, sums-of-squares

Many posts (i.e. [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4544/how-does-one-do-a-type-iii-ss-anova-in-r-with-contrast-codes) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/23197/conflicting-results-of-type-iii-sum-of-squares-in-anova-in-sas-and-r)) discuss how the Type III sums of squares produced by car::Anova() in R
are incorrect or nonsensical under R's default model parameterization, "contr.treatment", in which the first level of
the categorical variable is set as the reference/intercept and each remaining level is compared to it.  One way to
obtain the "correct" Type III sums of squares is to change the model parameterization to [sum coding](https://marissabarlaz.github.io/portfolio/contrastcoding/#:%7E:text=In%20order%20to%20set%20a,the%20contrasts%20on%20that%20variable.), "contr.sum".

What remains unclear to me, however, is whether there might be situations in which the default "incorrect" Type III sums of squares under the "contr.treatment" parameterization might be useful.  What is the interpretation of these sums of squares for the main effects, and are they always nonsensical and useless?

Below is some example R code for illustration:

```
# Random data for 2-way balanced ANOVA design
set.seed(2964)
df <- data.frame(response = rnorm(n = 32, mean = seq(10, 25, 5)), 
             varA = factor(rep(paste0("A", 1:4), times = 4)),
             varB = factor(rep(paste0("B", 1:2), each = 8)))

# Type I Sums of Squares
anova(lm(response ~ varA*varB, data = df))

# Default "incorrect" Type III Sums of Squares
car::Anova(lm(response ~ varA*varB, data = df), 
       type = "III", 
       test.statistic = "F")

# "Correct" Type III Sums of Squares produced under sum coding
# These match the Type I Sums of Squares.
car::Anova(lm(response ~ varA*varB, data = df, 
          contrasts = list(varA = contr.sum, varB = contr.sum)), 
       type = "III", 
       test.statistic = "F")
```

#### Type I Sums of Squares

```
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: response
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq  F value               Pr(>F)    
varA       3 991.97  330.66 330.6870 < 0.0000000000000002 ***
varB       1   0.15    0.15   0.1494              0.70247    
varA:varB  3   9.23    3.08   3.0783              0.04666 *  
Residuals 24  24.00    1.00                                  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

#### Default "incorrect" Type III Sums of Squares

```
Anova Table (Type III tests)

Response: response
            Sum Sq Df  F value                Pr(>F)    
(Intercept) 322.18  1 322.2059  0.000000000000002052 ***
varA        545.68  3 181.9090 < 0.00000000000000022 ***
varB          6.03  1   6.0350               0.02164 *  
varA:varB     9.23  3   3.0783               0.04666 *  
Residuals    24.00 24                                   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

#### "Correct" Type III Sums of Squares produced under sum coding

These correctly match the Type I Sums of Squares for this balanced case.

```
Anova Table (Type III tests)

Response: response
            Sum Sq Df   F value               Pr(>F)    
(Intercept) 9666.9  1 9667.7398 < 0.0000000000000002 ***
varA         992.0  3  330.6870 < 0.0000000000000002 ***
varB           0.1  1    0.1494              0.70247    
varA:varB      9.2  3    3.0783              0.04666 *  
Residuals     24.0 24                                   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```