# Type II anova with poly contrasts matrix

Tags: r, anova

I need to conduct a type II anova. Therefore, I use the `Anova` function from the `car` package. In addition, for `Factor1` I want to use a polynomial contrast matrix to see linear and quadratic effects.

However, using the `Anova` function from the `car` package does not display the linear and quadratic effects compared to the normal `summary.lm(lm(...))` functions. Before I apply the `Anova` function from the `car` package I test for non significant interaction as that is required for doing a type II anova.

I was wondering how I can extract the linear and the quadratic effects from the `Anova` output.

Here is a working example in R:

http://pastebin.com/mfk5PEq1

Comment: Some examples of entering manual contrasts for use with `Anova` and `lm` were given on a related thread: http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/4549/930.