# Regression qualitative explanatory variables

Tags: regression, categorical-data, modeling, qualitative

I am trying to run a regression, taking StudentMarks as the dependent variable and regressing this on the following variables:

Nomadic/Semi Nomadic: if the Child lives in a nomadic family then performance would be affected

And, likewise more qualitative variables like

Caste , Religion, Traditional Family Occupation , Insurance are in my mind. These qualitative variables have many qualitative values that can be assumed by them and not just 2 , so if I try to use dummy variables then I will have to include a lot of dummies in the model.

I would have around 30 variables in my regression equation.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Categorical Predictors and categorical responses](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/157975/categorical-predictors-and-categorical-responses)

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen I think this one is about quantitative responses.  But it has to have been asked here somewhere.  As an aside, how do you find all these duplicates?  It's amazing.