# Output of aov() in R varies with changing order of independent variables

Tags: r, anova

I need to understand why does the summary output of `aov()` in R vary when the order of independent variable changes. Like for example:
`summary(aov(y~A+B, data))` is different from `summary(aov(y~B+A,data))`.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/60362/choice-between-type-i-type-ii-or-type-iii-anova?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: This is related to Type1 and Type 3. I'm 100% sure it's been answered.

Comment: http://myowelt.blogspot.com.au/2008/05/obtaining-same-anova-results-in-r-as-in.html is useful

Answer (score 3):

As [@SmallChess](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/34623/smallchess) pointed out,

> "The `anova` and `aov` functions in R implement a sequential sum of
>   squares (type I)." [[source]](http://goanna.cs.rmit.edu.au/~fscholer/anova.php)

This procedure has probably been tackled already by different questions in the site. Basically, it works like this [[source]](http://goanna.cs.rmit.edu.au/~fscholer/anova.php)

> The different types of sums of squares then arise depending on the
>   stage of model reduction at which they are carried out. In particular:
>
> - Type I, also called "sequential" sum of squares:
>
>   - SS(A) for factor A.
>   - SS(B | A) for factor B.
>   - SS(AB | B, A) for interaction AB.
>   - This tests the main effect of factor A, followed by the main effect of
>       factor B after the main effect of A, followed by the interaction
>       effect AB after the main effects.
>   - **Because of the sequential nature and the fact that the two main factors are tested in a particular order, this type of sums of squares
>       will give different results for unbalanced data depending on which
>       main effect is considered first.**

So the the effect of `B` in `summary(aov(y~A+B, data))` is tested in the presence of `A`, while the effect of `B` in `summary(aov(y~B+A, data))` is tested in the absence of `A`.

Answer (score -2):

Very likely your design is unbalanced. Try this function `!is.list(replications(y~A+B, data))` to see if this is so. If it is unbalanced, then you might try the `lm` function from the `nlme` package.

See this answer for more in depth information regarding decisions around unbalanced designs. 
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13241/the-order-of-variables-in-anova-matters-doesnt-it